# How to scale bottom-of-page text using TCPDF and keep it on the page?

Tags: php, formatting, tcpdf

I'm using TCPDF to create barcode labels.  The code works great until I tried to scale the price text to make it taller (more visible).  Now the bottom row of labels are spilling components onto later pages, including components that are not scaled.  It appears the ordinate value of the text along the bottom row of labels is off the bottom of the page and that is causing the problem, but I thought that setting the (x,y) value when calling procedures like MultiCell absolutely set the (x,y) value?.  Does anyone know how to fix this?  Can I force a large art board?  Can I move the object after it has been scaled?  Can I somehow recover from the off-page ordinate calculation?

The issue is in the create_label function, below.  The second MultiCell line is the scaled entry.  The specific effect on the bottom row of labels is that the description and price are correctly on the first label, but the barcode is forced to a second page.  The description and price of the second label are on the second page, but the barcode is forced to a third.  Etc.

```
function create_label($posx, $posy, $upc, $price, $desc){
    global $START_X, $START_Y, $INC_X, $INC_Y, $style, $pdf;
    $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 15);
    $pdf->MultiCell(1.00, 0.575, $desc, 0, 'L', false, 1, $START_X+($posx*$INC_X), $START_Y+($posy*$INC_Y), true, 1, false, true, 0.575, 'M', true);
    $pdf->SetFont('', 'B', '24');
    $pdf->StartTransform();
    $pdf->ScaleY('200',1.00,0.7+($posy*$INC_Y)); break;
    $pdf->MultiCell(1.00, 0.575, $price, 0, 'R', false, 1, $START_X+($posx*$INC_X)+1.00, $START_Y+($posy*$INC_Y), true, 1, false, true, 0.575, 'M', true);
    $pdf->StopTransform();
    $pdf->write1DBarcode($upc, 'UPCA', $START_X+($posx*$INC_X), $START_Y+($posy*$INC_Y)+0.3125+0.2625, 2.0, .3, '', $style, 'N');
}

$pdf = new TCPDF('P', 'in', 'LETTER', true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->SetMargins(0.1875, 0.5, 0.1875);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(0);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(0);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 0.5);
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
  require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
  $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}
$pdf->AddPage();

$START_X = 0.85;
$START_Y = 0.38;
$INC_X = 2.375;
$INC_Y = 0.9375;

// label width = 2.25
// label height = 0.875
// Label gutter = 1/8 x 1/16

$upc_list = array( /*Array of UPC numbers*/ );
for($row = 0; $row <= 10; $row++){
    for ($col = 0; $col <= 2; $col++){
        unset($upc);
        if(strlen($upc) > 0 && strlen($upc) < 13 && is_numeric($upc)) {
            unset($item);
            $item = get_item_from_database($upc);  // Creates data array
            create_label($col, $row, $upc, $item['price'], trim($item['description']));
        }
    }
}
$pdf->Output('test_pdf.pdf', 'I');
```

Comment: I tried $pdf->setPage('1') before write1DBarcode, but that didn't work.  I tried it after write1DBarcode and the descriptions and price of the labels are in the correct place, but the barcodes are on page 2.  This would have been a hack solution, but I would have used it had it worked.

Comment: OK!  It's remarkable how valuable just asking the question helps.  Annoying, though, that I can't answer my own question within 8 hours until I have a higher reputation.  Oh well...  The auto page break command

    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 0.5);

set the trigger-point for a new page to 0.5".  When the scale function ordinate crossed that line, it invoked a new page even though the result of the scale did not cross the trigger line.  Turning SetAutoPageBreak to FALSE did *not* work.  I had to set the trigger to 0".

    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 0.0);